# Using a .mov file as Boot Animation in Android

Tags: android, boot-animation

I went through a lot of posts about changing the default boot animation of Android. I want to change the default boot animation with a .mov file. How can I do it?
I have gone through the concept of bootanimation.zip file. Is there a way i can use the .mov file without using any png files in the bootanimation.zip

Comment: seems doubtful. .mov would need to be decoded by quicktime... i would think it woud be easier to grab frames out of the .mov and setup the bootanimation.zip than to find a kludge to allow a video codec to operate at startup...

Comment: @polarysekt yes that seems the only way out now. I was wondering if I could use the .mov file as a whole. Thanks